# How do I replace a dimmer switch to conventional for a fan?

Tags: dimmer-switch, fans

question on my setup. I am taking out dimmer and light switch that adjust separately and replacing it with one switch as my new light/fan is on a remote. I am assuming I need a 3 way switch. black common I understand but then I have 2 wires going to fan/light and coming in fan/light - red and black. Now on the switch I assume I will put them as runners, BUT which wire I connect to the fan/light black wire? black, red or both?[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Think for 5 seconds before attempting electrical work.

Presently you have two separate devices controlling the fan, and the light, from this one location.

So you have

1. constant hot (or constant live) from the power source
2. and switched hot (switched live) for the lights (on a dimmer)
3. and switched hot (switched live) for the fan.

That is NOT a **3-way**. It's **two** functions, which you are now eliminating one of. If you had a 3-way, there would be another switch that controlled the lights or fan, and more wires in this box.

So, cap off both ends of black (or red, pick one) in the cable that goes from switch to fan, and use the other one.

*If this is the only wall-switched light in the room, it had better come on when you throw the switch, without needing to find the remote, or you're violating code.*